# How to manage multiple inheritance on jpa

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

Hello everyone i have a problem to perform operations in jpa with four multi-inhentaded tables.
I have four entites

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Offer extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "offer_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "offer_seq", sequenceName = "offer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;    

 //... other fields

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<>();


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<PriceIndex> prices = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "offer",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<VolRiskOff> volRiskOff = new HashSet<>();


 //... constructors , getters and setters
}
```

this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_index")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class PriceIndex extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "price_index_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "price_index_seq", sequenceName = "price_index_seq", 
allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;

 //... other fields

@ManyToOne
private Offer offer;

@ManyToOne
private Customer customer;

  //... constructors , getters and setters
}
```

this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vol_risk_off")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class VolRiskOff implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "vol_risk_off_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "vol_risk_off_seq", sequenceName = "vol_risk_off_seq", 
allocationSize = 1)
private Long id;
  
  //... other fields

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name = "offer_id")
private Offer offer;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "price_index_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private PriceIndex priceIndex;

 //... constructors , getters and setters
}
```

and this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Customer extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customer_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_seq", sequenceName = "customer_seq", 
allocationSize=1)
private Long id;
 

   //... other fields

@ManyToOne
private Offer offer;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<PriceIndex> priceIndexes = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonIgnore
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Set<VolRiskOff> volRiskOff = new HashSet<>();

 //... constructors , getters and setters
 }
```

all of them worked right untill i added vol_risk_off table and i tried to delete customers from the offer.
how the classes are now configuered doent gave any error, but if i try to delete customer a its related priceIndex and volRiskOff all related at the same offer and the customer is in both priceIndex and volRiskOff.
So my question is how can manage classes to make all operation works without anyt conflict?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the mappings themselves, but your use case is wrong. When you 'dereference' or remove a customer from an Offer, you've got orphanRemoval = true set on the relationship which forces JPA to delete the customer row from the database. What you then do with any VolRiskOff instances that references the customer you are deleting (or aren't doing with them) is what is causing you problems. What exactly do you want to happen with those references? Orphan removal is only for special use cases; you might be using this by mistake

Comment: Regardless, to delete or remove a customer you are going to have to clean up any and all references to it in your object model. here, that means finding all VolRiskOff (and possibly Offers) and nulling out references to the customer (or removing those entity instances) before you can remove the customer.